# In PRAW, is there a way to get the comment streams for multiple users?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

With PRAW, I know you can do

`subs = reddit.subreddit("Pics+Funny")`

to get the streams of both r/Pics and r/Funny, and I know you can do this

`user = reddit.redditor("spez")`

to get one user, but is there a way to get multiple users at once? Like so:

`users = reddit.redditor("spez+kn0wthing")`?

I'm trying to read the comments of a large group of users, and I would like to know if something like this is possible. When I tried what I put right above this, it returned a 404 error. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: You can do `reddit.subreddit("Pics+Funny")` because that's how [multireddits work](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/9t50jp/what_is_a_multireddit_how_do_i_access/) -- try http://www.reddit.com/r/nostupidquestions+explainlikeimfive. I don't think there's an equivalent way to do users.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this as you can with multireddits. However, there is a way around this with the `pause_after` parameter in praw comment streams.

e.g.

```
spezStream = reddit.redditor('spez').stream.comments(pause_after=-1)
kn0thingStream = reddit.redditor('kn0thing').stream.comments(pause_after=-1)

while True:
    for comment in spezStream:
        print(comment.body)
    for comment in kn0thingStream:
        print(comment.body)
```

And that should work :-)

[Documentation here.](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/util.html?highlight=pause_after#praw.models.util.stream_generator)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a built-in way to do this. Either you'll need to loop through the users one at a time or create separate threads and merge the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
for comment in reddit.redditor('spez+kn0thing').stream.comments(skip_existing=True):
   #do stuff with comment
```

Should work. You can also add them as friends and stream comments from /r/friends